# Cleaning Project not fixing R.java errors (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, r.java-file

My Android project just started saying all my R.blah.blah references are errors. Cleaning/re-generating the R.java file has not fixed it. Nor has closing/reopening the project/eclipse. I undid any changes to xml files that could have caused it. This is only occurring in ONE of my activities, all other activities do not have any errors related to R.blah.

Note: R.java does have all the correct references in the file.

Comment: check if R is imported into your imports and remove it then try

Comment: That was it. import android.R was there for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, happens to me sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if

```
import android.R;
```

is in your classes and remove it then try

Answer (score 1):

If you copy code from other project you get some,lines like

```
import android.R.com.example.view.Widget
import android.R.com.hardware.Camera
```

Remove those lines and run it.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the hussle ,another simple  solution is to restart eclipse. This time change  the directory of your workspace. And import your project from the previous workspace into the new one . Viola.it works. So far as you have not violated naming conventions in  your xml files (Remember all ids in xml must be small letters) . This should work.

Answer (score 0):

This may Error with your xml data..Check your xml file [refer here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/package-summary.html) and then cleaning your project and build it..check that R.java file is generating automatically or not.

Answer (score 0):

just try it out in that particular activity where errors occured

```
    import your_package_name.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `android:text="@string/Get Location"` causes as error in R.java because string `Get Location` have a gap in it.

To correct it use an underscore between two names: `Get_Location`